# TextView#setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) is breaking link display

Tags: android, html, textview, spannable, linkmovementmethod

I have a `TextView` that I am populating with a `Spannable` made from some HTML.

This code:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textContent, mImageGetter, null));
```

displays links, but they aren't clickable.  This code:

```
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textContent, mImageGetter, null));
```

*doesn't* display the links.  The `TextView` is specified in the XML as

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/another_textview"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textColorLink="@color/link_color_unpressed"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Why does `LinkMovementMethod`, a method that exists entirely to make links in a `TextView` clickable, stop links from displaying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit was the auto-link method:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:autoLink="web"
    ...
    />
```

Removing this line fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful, me from the past!

Comment: Thanks. This also help me a lot, but I still don't know what the function of "autoLink" is. When should I use it. @Andrew

Comment: `autoLink` is supposed to convert detected linkable text in any `TextView` into clickable links.  It works for web, email addresses, and phone numbers (well, actually, any long numbers).  It's pretty handy but not as controllable as HTML.  It also interacts destructively with methods available to render HTML in a `TextView` which may contain `<a ... ></a>` tags.